# Writing to excel using jxl, getting indexOutofBoundException error

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, jxl

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException{


WritableWorkbook workbookCP;
    try {       
        Workbook workbook =  Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/collections.xls"));
        workbookCP = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/collectionsCopy.xls"),workbook);
        WritableSheet sheet = workbookCP.getSheet("collections");
        Label label = new Label(10, 0, "Name");
        sheet.addCell(label);
        Label label1 = new Label(11, 0, "Surname");
        sheet.addCell(label1);
        Label label2 = new Label(13, 0, "Ammount");
        sheet.addCell(label2);
        workbookCP.write();
        workbookCP.close();
        workbook.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

i'm trying to write data to an existing excel file with the code above, but i'm getting the following error
Thanks

```
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 this means that there are no elements and you are trying to retrieve the first element.

Comment: That most probably happens on `workbookCP.getSheet("collections")`

Comment: You should use create Sheet instant of get sheet to resolve the issue . You are trying to access the sheet which is not existing .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these two lines:

```
Workbook workbook =  Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/collections.xls"));
workbookCP = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/collectionsCopy.xls"),workbook);
```

into this:

```
Workbook workbook =  Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\Users\\collections.xls"));
workbookCP = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\Users\\collectionsCopy.xls"),workbook);
```